# What are the eligibility criteria for hardware-based PlayStation Stars collectibles?

Tags: psn, playstation-stars

PlayStation Stars recently launched, offering digital "collectibles" for completing certain tasks. Some tasks have had hidden requirements and only show up for certain users. These include the PS3:

[image: Digital model of a PS3, PlayStation Stars collectible]

...and the PS VR headset:

[image: Digital model of a PS VR headset, PlayStation Stars collectible]

I've been seeing conflicting reports about which accounts are eligible for which collectibles, most commonly seeing that users who made a PSN account on a PS3 between 2006-2008 get the PS3 collectible. **Is it known yet what the actual requirements are?**

Anecdotally, I've unlocked the PS VR collectible (bought the headset at launch in 2016, earned several trophies in various games), but not the PS3 collectible (made my PSN account on a PSP in early 2008, bought a 160 GB PS3 in early 2009).